# VST unable to be loaded after links with Google Breakpad

Tags: macos, vst, google-breakpad

I'm trying to build a 32-bit VST plugin on OSX and link it with Google Breakpad.
Breakpad.framework can be built by following official guide
https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/wiki/MacBreakpadStarterGuide

But the VST is no longer able to be loaded by MuLab and failed with the following error:
FSOpenResFile with error -1409

Is there any people encountered this issue?

Comment: Hi, i have the same issue. If you find a solution, please let me know. Thanks.